# Symfony Key "name" for array with keys "0" does not exist. BUT IT EXISTS

Tags: php, arrays, function, symfony

Most emberassing for me: i just used the exact function yesterday, copied to a new project and suddenly broken.

Here is the Function in my symfony to find database entrys by column type:

```
/**
     * @Route("/type/{type}", name="sort_page", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function sort($type, EventRepository $eventRepository): Response
    {  
        $events1 = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("App:Event")->findByType($type);
      dd($events1);
        return $this->render('event/sort.html.twig', [
            'event' => $events1,
        ]);
    }
```

As you see i did Dump & Die for $events1
it gives this result

```
EventController.php on line 102:
array:1 [▼
  0 => Event^ {#2919 ▼
    -id: 1
    -name: "Schnitzel"
    -date: DateTime @1435701600 {#2387 ▶}
    -time: DateTime @7440 {#2337 ▶}
    -descr: "Test"
    -img: "test"
    -capacity: "65456"
    -mail: "adsd@ds.com"
    -phone: "324"
    -city: "dsfs"
    -zip: 65456
    -address: "asdasd"
    -web: "asdasd"
    -type: "asdasd"
  }
]
```

But if i put this code in the sort.html.twig pages

```
{{ event.name }}
```

Key "name" for array with keys "0" does not exist.
i get the error message

Comment: you should iterate the collection

Comment: thanks thats the answer i totally forgot about it the ultra basic stuff. feels stupid man :D

Comment: Glad it was solved. I voted close because it's essentially a typo and your question will probably not be relevant to others searching a similar issue in the future.